# Use works "of" or "by"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

He played works **OF** / **BY** Bach?

The works are by Bach, but the ones you play are also by him? or of him?

Answer (score 1):

Both mean approximately the same thing.

The works **of** Bach are those we can call "his".  The works **by** Bach are those he composed.

**by** highlights the agency of the artist.  **of** highlights the attribution of authorship.